# База Данных к игре "Русские Шашки"

Tags: java, база-данных

Для курсового проекта дописываю игру "Русские шашки" на Java. Требуют "допилить" БД, которая будет храниться на стороннем сервере. Могли бы Вы мне, уважаемые форумчане, подкинуть какую-нибудь идею насчет БД, а именно чтобы мне в ней хранить?

Сразу на ум приходит Highscore какой-нибудь хранить, но база будет скудной =(

Не нужно чего-то сложного. Просто, чтобы она пришлась бы к месту. 
К слову, в моей реализации "Русских шашек" имеются два режима игры: с компьютером и с игроком.

Спасибо заранее! :D

Comment: для того чтоб хранить историю игр пользователейнадо авторизация и регистрация. последняя подразумевает хранение какой-то инфы о пользователях. если подкрутить немного то этого будет достаточно чтоб от вас отцепились

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- можно хранить пользователей.
- можно хранить партии. А потом переигрывать их, делать анализ (даже вплоть до того, сколько времени тратил игрок на ход).
- можно хранить набор этюдов, которые разыгрывать с компьютером.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)'а:

- можно организовать онлайн-турнир, и хранить результаты (и показывать на отдельной страничке)
- соответственно, можно высчитать рейтинг участников
- кто с кем играл, и чтоб можно было узнать, какой счёт по личным встречам

Answer (score 2):

В шашках очень нужна возможность демонстрации партий с комментариями. Если их хранить в базе данных то можно будет в любой момент транслировать их на сайтах. Если отдельно в базе хранить фамилии игроков, то это позволит в любой момент получить доступ к статистике каждого игрока.

Comment: @keshun, здесь всем интересно. Пишите тут.

Comment: Здесь так здесь.
У меня есть реализованный метод демонстрации партий по русским шашкам _http://shashkinn.ru/servis-translyacii-shashechnyx-partij-russkie-shashki/ (написан на js), но в нем есть несколько недостатков + он не использует базы данных. Вернее использует, но скорее как дополнение. Весь текст партии передается скрипту с вызываемой страницы.

Comment: Если кто-то будет делать что-то подобное, то нужно что бы вызов на веб-страницах любых сайтов был предельно простым (а-ля кнопка "поделиться" на youtube). В коде должна передаваться необходимая информация, по которой уже будет однозначно определяться требуемая партия для просмотра.

Но шашисты-практики не оценили такую трансляцию. Им еще нужна возможность добавления комментариев внутрь текста партии (комментарии видимо тоже хранятся в базе).

Comment: Т.е. в идеале:
1. Есть сервис с текстовым полем. 
2. Пользователь вводит в него текст партии с комментариями (комментарии определяет специальным тегом)
3. Сервис выдает короткий фрагмент кода, вставив который на свой сайт или форум, пользователь сможет отобразить свою партию

Вот как то так.

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить:

1. Профили игрока.
2. Партии которые сыграл игрок (время, результат, сложность).
3. Таблицу рекордов всех профилей.
4. Таблицу рекордов всех пользователей по сети.
5. Можно хранить ходы партии (к примеру, ход 1. Компьютер: Е1, А3).

Можно придумать еще довольно много и все будет иметь смысл. Успехов! Надеюсь помог :D

Comment: К сожалению, автор вопроса уже три года не заходил на сайт. ))